# argument suspected not referring to proper variables

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I am trying to understand what is going on here. I have two variables `activeToInactive` and `inactiveToActive` and I increment them whenever I update a status. Here is my code first of all

Counter Service:

```js
export class CounterService {
    // Initial States
    activeToInactive = 0
    inactiveToActive = 0
    
    incrementStatusCount(statusCount: number) {
        // Increment either of the initial states whenever the function is called.
        statusCount++
        if (statusCount == this.activeToInactive) {
            console.log(`${statusCount} - active to inactive`)
        }
        if (statusCount == this.inactiveToActive) {
            console.log(`${statusCount} - inactive to aactive`)
        }
        // I notice that statusCount does equal the initial states so if statements evaluate to false
        
    }
}
```

Transfer Service:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CounterService } from "./counter.service";

@Injectable()
export class transferService {

    constructor(private Counter: CounterService) {}
    activeUsers = ['Max', 'Anna'];
    inactiveUsers = ['Chris', 'Manu']  
    
    setToInactive(id: number) {
        this.inactiveUsers.push(this.activeUsers[id]);
        this.activeUsers.splice(id, 1);


        // Calling the function in a different service
        this.Counter.incrementStatusCount(this.Counter.activeToInactive)
    }
      
    setToActive(id: number) {
        this.activeUsers.push(this.inactiveUsers[id]);
        this.inactiveUsers.splice(id, 1);

        // Calling the function in a different service
        this.Counter.incrementStatusCount(this.Counter.inactiveToActive)
    }  
}
```

When either function in Transfer Service is called, the initial states do not increment. All I know is that `statusCount` does NOT equal to any of the initial states. Does this have to do with references? I haven't mastered them but if you have any tips on how I can approach this then let me know.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.

In the `incrementStatusCount`function, you are receiving a parameter `statusCount`, which you intend to use for incrementing either `activeToInactive` or `inactiveToActive` based on the value passed to the function.

However, in the `TransferService`, when you call `this.Counter.incrementStatusCount(this.Counter.activeToInactive)` and `this.Counter.incrementStatusCount(this.Counter.inactiveToActive)`, you are passing the initial values of `activeToInactive` and `inactiveToActive` instead of the actual counts that you want to increment. So let's just use `inactiveToActive` and `activeToInactive` directly.

Update your CounterService like this:

```
incrementStatusCount(incrementActiveToInactive: boolean) {
    // Increment either of the initial states based on the provided flag.
    if (incrementActiveToInactive) {
        this.activeToInactive++;
        console.log(`${this.activeToInactive} - active to inactive`);
    } else {
        this.inactiveToActive++;
        console.log(`${this.inactiveToActive} - inactive to active`);
    }
}
```

Your TranserService will only slightly change, like so:

```
setToInactive(id: number) {
        this.inactiveUsers.push(this.activeUsers[id]);
        this.activeUsers.splice(id, 1);

        // Call the function with the correct flag
        this.Counter.incrementStatusCount(true);
    }

    setToActive(id: number) {
        this.activeUsers.push(this.inactiveUsers[id]);
        this.inactiveUsers.splice(id, 1);

        // Call the function with the correct flag
        this.Counter.incrementStatusCount(false);
    }
```